# Copy text of an anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor element with an email address inside of it, and I want it to be an anchor element so it's clear you can click on it when the cursor changes.

I googled around a bit and found a solution on another Stack Overflow question, but the way it works it adds an event listener to 'copy', which will mean that after you've clicked on it once, attempting to manually copy anything else will result in copying the text of the anchor element again.

```js
        clickToCopy.on('click', function(event) {
            var copyText = $(this).text();

            document.addEventListener('copy', function copyWorkaround(e) {
                console.log(e)
                e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copyText);
                e.preventDefault();
            }, true);

            console.log(document.execCommand('copy'))

            event.preventDefault()
        })
```

This is the code. I can't figure out how to remove the event listener afterwards, or how to do it without adding the second event listener in the first place.

Comment: Would `document.remveEventListener('copy', copyWorkaround)` work?

Comment: No, Uncaught ReferenceError: copyWorkaround is not defined

Comment: May you update the example? I can't see how you're using it to get that error.

Comment: I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: "removeEventListener at the end does not work" - what's the issue?

Comment: It throws the ReferenceError from above. copyWorkaround is not defined.

Comment: Move `copyWorkaround` above the event listener, and only pass in the function name? `addEventListener('click', copyWorkaround)`

Comment: It's not throwing any errors now, but for whatever reason it's also not removing the event listener. I tried this earlier but I tried defining the copyWorkaround function outside of clickToCopy and I wasn't sure how I would pass it copyText, oops.

Comment: I'm a little bemused why this work around is even needed.

Comment: Try putting `document.remveEventListener('copy', copyWorkaround)` inside `copyWorkaround`?

Comment: I have tried simply using .select() and document.execCommand('copy') but it did nothing. I am fairly certain it has to be an input tag for it to work. What's even weirder is that in the parameters for addEventListener I am passing true for 'once,' meaning it should only run the one time and then remove itself on its own, but it isn't doing that. Could it be the browser I am using? (It's Opera GX)

Comment: Alright, I have fixed it. I will edit the solution in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to present a simpler alternative via [`navigator.clipboard.writeText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText). This snippet doesn't run on SO (probably because it's in an iframe), but I just tested it locally and it seems to work just fine.

```js
document.querySelector('.js-copy').addEventListener('click', event => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(event.target.textContent);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a class="js-copy" href="#">email@email.com</a>
```

Comment: This worked great for me, and its a much simpler solution compared to others I've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fix: It seems I was only passing true for the first parameter in options, doing this instead should pass 'once' as true, and the event listener will remove itself after occurring the one time.

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', copyWorkaround, [true, true, false])
```

Comment: That's not the correct format for the addEventListener options parameter. It should be an object, not an array: `{capture, once, passive}`. See [.addEventListener Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters).